# Getting Windows 2003 server updated to run .Net 3.5

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, .net

I need to install .NET Framework 3.5 on a Windows 2003 Server. This is server has 'just been running' for several years with no updates. It appears it is not even on SP1. I have Googled, but found no good steps on how to get this old beast updated for this version of .NET

Specs:

Over 50 GB free Hard drive space
Xeon 2.80GHz Processor
2 GB RAM

Is there a simple download to make this happen? We are an Apple shop and not Windows Server specialists.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just running Windows Update should bring you up to .NET 3.5.  You can tell by visiting C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework.  Do you have a v3.5 folder?

As long as it's installed then in terms of selecting the version by IIS, just select v2.0 and it will really be v3.5 too.  v3.5 is just a set of extensions on top of v2.0, so the parent framework is v2.0 (confusing, I know).

If for some reason it's not installed with Windows Update, then you can obtain it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22.